# How do I configure net-ssh so I can fetch data using rest-client through an ssh tunnel?

Tags: ruby, rest-client, ssh-tunnel, net-ssh

We have an elasticsearch setup that is only available from a jump box.  I want to set up an ssh tunnel so I can query from my laptop or a Docker container.
When I run ssh, either directly or via 'system' the tunnel works and my post fetches data.  When I try to set up the tunnel using net-ssh I get a RestClient::Exceptions::ReadTimeout.  I'm not sure what I'm missing in the net-ssh configuration.  I've provided a simplified code example.

Tried running this on Windows with Cygwin, and in a Docker container running Centos7.

```
require 'json'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'rest-client'

def fetchData
  indexName = "REDACTED"
  url = "http://localhost:9999/#{indexName}/_search?pretty"
  body = '{"size":1, "query":{"match_all":{}}}'
  resp = RestClient.post url, body, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
  return JSON.parse(resp)
end

begin
  userName   = 'REDACTED'
  privateKey = 'id_rsa'
  jumpBoxUrl = 'REDACTED.com'
  elasticUrl = 'REDACTED.com'

  # this works
  system("ssh -fN -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/#{privateKey} #{userName}@#{jumpBoxUrl} -p 22 -L 9999:#{elasticUrl}:9200 sleep 10 >> logfile")
  puts fetchData

  # wait for the ssh to time out
  sleep 5

  # Timed out reading data from server (RestClient::Exceptions::ReadTimeout) - WHY?!
  #
  Net::SSH.start(jumpBoxUrl, userName, :port=>22, :forward_agent=>true, :verbose=>:info, :keys=>["~/.ssh/#{privateKey}"]) do |session|
    session.forward.local(9999, elasticUrl, 9200)

    # this works - able to authenticate to the shell box
    puts session.exec!("ls -la")

    # this times out - data is not returned
    puts fetchData
  end
end
```

I expect the post to return the same data when using net-ssh as it does when using ssh.

Appreciate any help with what I'm missing in my net-ssh setup.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's related to the port forwarding. Inside that block you should be able to access `elasticUrl:9200` since you're essentially on the jumphost at that point.

My suggestion would be to ssh into the jumphost and `curl` the API endpoint as test. If that works, you should be able to copy that command verbatim and pass it to `session.exec!`. And finally if that works, then you should be able to update `fetchData` to make the request to `elasticUrl:9200` and you're off to the races.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, unfortunately, that defeats the purpose.  I'm trying to use ruby, not a bunch of external programs.  I can already use 'ssh' externally, as shown in the sample code, and that works w/o introducing curl.  I want just ruby (ignoring whatever the gems are doing that might require C, etc.).